# Get struct within a struct using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, struct

I'm having problems accessing A struct within a struct

```
namespace Some.NameSpace.ToAccess
{
    public struct HowTo
    {
        public const string Some_Static_Strings = "redudantString";
        public const string SomeOtherStatic_Strings = "someOtherRedundantString";
        public const string Option3 = SomeOption";

        public struct AccessMe
        {
            public static readonly string OPTION1 = 1.ToString;
            public static readonly string OPTION2 = 2.ToString;
            public static readonly string OPTION3 = 4.ToString;
            public static readonly string OPTION0 = 0.ToString;

            static AccessMe()
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have looked at other similar questions however mine differs in that I'm also loading the assembly at runtime rather than just using reflection to get the contents of a specific struct at runtime. So to reitterate I have no reference to the library I'm itterating over prior to runtime.

this is very similar to my issue [Get struct within struct using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681082/get-struct-within-struct-using-reflection), however I can't do

```
FieldInfo FI = typeof(HowTo).GetType().GetField("Collection", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

because I need to get the type first, however this also doesnt work

```
var result = _someClass.PreLoadedAssembly.GetType("Some.NameSpace.ToAccess.HowTo").GetField("AccessMe", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

(PreLoadedAssembly being the Assembly I've loaded at runtime and stored in _someClass)

Any help would be appreciated as I'm not getting very far.
Thanks

Comment: The nested struct is *not* a field. It's a type.

Comment: As @Ondrej pointed out, its Type.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [GetNestedType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kekdz4kb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
_someClass.PreLoadedAssembly
          .GetType("Some.NameSpace.ToAccess.HowTo")
          .GetNestedType("AccessMe");
```

Comment: A better match might be `.GetNestedType("AccessMe")`